# Need Help on Creating XPCOM...!

Tags: xpcom

I want to create an XPCom, which I want to use to get Mozilla DOM, object in my C# application. I am really very new bee for this.

Can some one tell me exact steps? 
Like from starting with C++ to create XPCOM and to end with C# which can get the DOM of firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Can't advice for C#, but you can check [my post on C++ XPCOM add-ons](http://ptncode.blogspot.com/2013/08/exposing-xpcom-c-interface-on-dom.html) for some insights on this. I'm quite new for this as well, so I've tried to gather info and describe steps more or less...